# Yocto Rocko bitbake process reboot on Ubuntu

Tags: yocto

Yocto Rocko bitbake on Ubuntu 16.04 Machine reboots after reaching a particular stage. The PC running Ubuntu has a RAM of 16 GB. How to overcome this issue?

Comment: Share bitbake log, dmesg. Without any information it's hard to judge your problem.

Comment: Reduce the number of concurrent build/resource usages by adding `BB_NUMBER_THREADS = "2"` to your `conf/local.conf` file

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

**Switch to another tty (pressing CTRL + ALT + F[1-6]), login and run bitbake from there.**

The root cause seems to be a SIGNAL sent by bitbake and not correctly handled by the X server: http://lists.openembedded.org/pipermail/openembedded-core/2016-December/130621.html.

The first workaround suggested was to lower the concurrent bitbake processes setting BB_NUMBER_THREADS to, at least, 4 (but I've experienced soft reboot also with 4 concurrent threads and I had to lower it to 2 to be able to compile).
Unfortunately, this workaround implies longer building time (as if it were not already slow enough)

By the way, there is another workaround: instead of launching the bitbake command inside your tty7, default console where the X server is running, just switch to another tty (pressing CTRL + ALT + F[1-6]), login and run bitbake from there.
Doing this, I was able to build an entire image with 7 concurrent threads without experiencing soft reboots.

Another option is to use an awesome desktop/tiling manager: i3.

Answer (score 0):

`CTRL + ALT + F1` to another tty helped me greatly, I can run `bitbake` with **8** running tasks.

(this is already answered by @garlix, I just highlighted it as my easiest way to do).

Comment: use `CTRL + ALT + F7` to swtich back to GUI (X server)